# Dictionary of a dictionary with duplicate keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pymongo

I want to insert the below data structure into MongoDB using pyMongo. Only thing is that the xml data I am using has duplicate keys which I want to preserve, as well as the 'keyword' and 'relevance' sub dictionary keys.

```
for entity in root.find('output'):
   oc_entities[entity.tag] = {'keyword' : entity.text,
  'relevance' : entity.get('relevance')}
```

The above is working and inserting as required, buy I am loosing most of my duplicate key value data. I am aware dictionaries do not permit duplicate keys, but a bit stumped as to an alternative!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the values be a list if there are duplicate keys.  This is a pretty common way of solving this problem.

```
for entity in root.find('output'):
   if oc_entities.get(entity.tag):
     if type(oc_entities.get(entity.tag)) == 'dict':
       oc_entities[entity.tag] = [oc_entities[entity.tag]]
     oc_entities[entity.tag].append({'keyword' : entity.text, 'relevance' : entity.get('relevance')})
   else:
     oc_entities[entity.tag] = {'keyword' : entity.text, 'relevance' : entity.get('relevance')}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I can have both a key and value in a list? (I'm new to Python!).

Comment: It would be a list of dicts, as I showed you above.  The only thing is that if you just have one element, it's a one element list.  You can get around this by putting in your if statements...I was just too lazy to do it.

You'd basically get rid of the brackets around the dict in the else statement, and then you'd do a check in the if clause to see if the type of the element is list...if not then make it a list...aw screw it i'll just do it.

Comment: Nice one. Commented before the code was shown! Great solution, and works a treat. Many thanks!

Comment: You could probably optimize this code more, but that's the general concept.